# Change blog comments display order

Tags: 7

I have a Drupal 7 site with blog and comments enabled for certain user groups and the users complain that in longer discussions like [this one](http://preferans.de/node/58) the order of comments is totally chaotic, they just can't follow it.

Is there please a way to change the order? I'd be happy with all blog comments sorted by the creation date.

I've looked around, but couldn't find any blog settings. I've tried to construct my own path **admin/content/blog/settings** too, but there was nothing about sorting.

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the "threading" option for each node type on the node type form (eg. on `admin/structure/types/manage/article`, where 'article' is the name of your content type). Deselecting that will put all comments in chronological order.

As far as I can see, the setting for the sort order (newest first/oldest first) was removed in [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/506218), but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thanks, but http://preferans.de/admin/structure/types/manage/article prints the Drupal error "page not found"

Comment: You have to change 'article' for the name of your content type :)