# How to add "load more" link to comments?

Tags: comments

I am trying to style my comments list to be similar to Facebook comments, so that user can load more comments by clicking on a link to load more. If there is a big number of comments then he should be able to load more and more comments.

Any suggestions how to start this?

Answer (score 3):

[Views Infinite Scroll](http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) and many similar modules allows you just that.

> Views Infinite Scroll provides a Pluggable pager that enables views infinite scrolling ( autopaging, depaging, endless pages ...you name it) by using jquery.autopager plugin. using this module with views page display will load another page whenever the user reaches bottom of the page.

[Views Load More](http://drupal.org/project/views_load_more) is other example.

> Yes, this is indeed, Yet another load more pager for views.

And you can show anything with Views. Comments too.

Comment: This can be used with views .. but how to use it with comments

Comment: Create a view displaying comments? Or google for similar module that works on them natively? Most people write things like that for views, as you can show anything with views - so you can use their creations on anything and they don't need to bother.

Answer (score 3):

This module does a similar thing, [More Comments](http://drupal.org/project/morecomments)

> More Comments module replaces the default pager of comments with a
>   button that loads the next page of comments using ajax.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it's very useful ,, any idea how to make it load the previous comments not the recent.. bcs this module shows the old comments and hides the previous

Comment: check this post http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2444/drupal-7-change-blog-comments-display-order and this talk and modules http://drupal.org/project/comment_goodness, http://drupal.org/project/sort_comments you will get suitable one